# Push a specific viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have 2 storyboards and in storyboard 1 I have a login page, in the storyboard 2, I have my main page! So the problem is in my main page, i have button for logging out, and when the user press the button I want to go back to my login page, I have already tried some methods that doesn't work for me! 
I tried:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And:

```
for controller in self.navigationController!.viewControllers as Array { if controller.isKind(of: ViewController) { self.navigationController!.popToViewController(controller, animated: true) break } }
```

So, any ways to get back to my login page??

Comment: Do you use a navigation controller on the login page? How do you push the main page from the login page?

Comment: Yes I have! I use segue for pushing, and in my main page, i have another navigation controller + buttom tab controller

Comment: From you main page, try `self.navigationController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated:true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code doesn't work, I suppose that your login view controller is not in navigation stack. Here's what you can try.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)

if let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() {
    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it work like a charm! And I got another problem! I'll post it below

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "1", bundle: nil)
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ID") as! LoginVC
    
if let nav = navigationController {
    nav.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}else {
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```